# GDAL rasterized shapefile does not contain any information about the polygon

Tags: python, gdal

I have the task of converting [a shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nq5gOCWMZSTtNDlOL9qHAjSSFH416W3L?usp=sharing) to raster data using GDAL with Python, but my result always return a blank GeoTIFF with all zero values. Is there anything wrong with my code or perhaps the file? (The file was created by me and displays correctly in ArcGIS, but if I call `geom.DumpReadable()` on the geometry, it does not dump a bunch of data points like I've seen from other files).

```
# path_shp is the path to the shapefile

ds = gdal.OpenEx(path_shp, gdal.OF_VECTOR) 
lyr = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
j = lyr.GetNextFeature()

path_out = 'something.tif'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
target_ds = driver.Create(path_out, 720, 360, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, None, None, [1])
target_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to use gdal.Rasterize and see usage examples from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_rasterize_lib.py.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would solve your current problem, but always remember to close you dataset when you are done with it.

Add this line at the end
`target_ds = ds = None`

Then, as @user30184 suggested in the comments, I also would recommend using `gdal.Rasterize` instead, its more flexible.

So for your example:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx(path_shp, gdal.OF_VECTOR) 
vector_uid = 'fid'  # Your column in the vector file you want to rasterize
x_pix_size = 10 
y_pix_size = 10     # Output resolution in the units of your vectorfile's coordinate system 

gdal.Rasterize('/path/to/rasterized.tif', ds,
               xRes=x_pix_size , yRes=y_pix_size ,
               attribute=vector_uid,
               allTouched=True)
ds=None
```

If you check out the python api you will find much more options to use with the `gdal.Rasterize` (https://gdal.org/python/ then search for RasterizeOptions)